# NextJS - Routing with different language

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I try to create multilanguage website with Next JS.

I'm using [next-translate](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate) package for translation.

For the posts I use static generation.

```
|-> pages
  |-> post
    |-> [slug].js
|-> i18n.json
|-> next.config.js
```

**Problem**

When I use default language ('tr') I successfully navigate **http://localhost:3000/post/title-tr**

But If I changed to language to 'en', library add 'en' to path then try to navigate **http://localhost:3000/en/post/title-en** and returns 404 page.

**Solution I tried**

In **next.config.js** I add rewrites method. But It didn't work.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate');

module.exports = nextTranslate({
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/en/post/:path*',
                destination: '/post',
            },
        ]
    },

    env: {
        NEXT_PUBLIC_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL,
    },
})
```

Where should I solve this problem? Routing, config files or Link component?

**i18n.json**

```
{
    "locales": ["tr", "en"],
    "defaultLocale": "tr",
    "pages": {
      "*": ["common","country","position"]
    }
}
```

**Link component I used**

```
<Link key={`L${item.id}`} href="/post/[slug]" as={`/post/${slug(item.title)}-${item.id}`}></Link>
```

**[slug].js**

```
function Post({ data }){
  return <>...</>
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
   const { data } = await fetch('fromAPI');
   return {
        paths: data.map(item => {
            return {
                params:
                {
                    slug: `${slug(item.title)}-${item.id}`
                }
            }
        }),
        fallback: false
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const { data } = await fetch('fromAPI');
    return { props: { data} }
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: Are you [statically exporting](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) the app? If not, have you considered using Next.js built-in [i18n Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing)?

Comment: Yes. This page will statically export. Actually, if  there is no prefix 'en' in url there is no problem. So I'll try to navigate /en/post/... to /post/...

Comment: Note that `rewrites` won't work with a statically exported Next.js app, you have to use [`exportPathMap`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap) to map paths to pages during the export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a path for every locale as shown in the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-routes-and-getstaticprops-pages

```
// [slug].js
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locales }) => {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { slug: 'post-1' }, locale: 'tr' },
      { params: { slug: 'post-1' }, locale: 'en' },
    ],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

> When I use default language ('tr') I successfully navigate http://localhost:3000/post/title-tr
> But If I changed to language to 'en', library add 'en' to path then
> try to navigate http://localhost:3000/en/post/title-en and returns 404
> page.

If no locale is provided only the defaultLocale will be generated.
If fallback is false, then any paths not returned by getStaticPaths will result in a 404 page. So right now you're only generating the defaultLocale "tr" and all other paths with different locales will result in a 404 page.

Comment: Note that while this is fine for SSG, it won't work with `next export` (which supposedly OP was using) since Next.js i18n routing [does not support it](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#how-does-this-work-with-static-generation).

Comment: Why are you destructuring `locales` from props when you do not use it?